# Get the form name of Facebook lead ads using webhook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I have two different Facebook leads ad campaigns (A and B) connected to the same F.B page, I've connected it to a webhook following this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.7) using Facebook ads PHP sdk, and pass the leads to my C.R.M, everything works fine, the problem is that **I can't tell if the lead came from form A or B**.

I've tried to pull the from name like this:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if($input)
{
    $form_id = $input['entry'][0]['changes'][0]['value']['form_id'];
    $form = AdsWebhookHandler::getFormName($form_id);
}
```

**From the `AdsWebhookHandler`class:**

```
public static function getFormName($form_id)
    {
        $form = new LeadgenForm($form_id);

        if(!$form) return $form_id;

        return $form->read();
    }
```

But the form always returns empty (`{}`) for some reason.
Does anybody know how can I pull the form name? or even better - is it possible to pass custom hidden fields in the form?

Thank you all for an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O.K so I figure out how to get the form name, all I needed to do is use the `getData()` function included in the Facebook PHP SDK, my code looks like this now:

```
public function getFormName($form_id)
{
    $form = new LeadgenForm($form_id,null,$this->fb_instance);

    if(!$form) return $form_id;

    $data = $form->read()->getData();
    return isset($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : $form_id;
}
```

Hope it'll help someone in the future :)